# NextJS Conditional CSS Import

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How do I conditionally import CSS stylesheet to the entire application?

```
{process.env.PARAMETER ? <link href="/localfonts.css" rel="stylesheet" /> : ''}
```

I added this to the document.tsx in pages, it didn't work. _app.tsx I attempted to import like

```
useEffect(() => { process.env.PARAMETER && import('localfonts.css');
```

this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I found the below to be the best option:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    process.env.PARAMETERS && require('localfonts.css');
```